# Calculate Character Frequency in Message using Perl

Tags: perl, frequency-analysis, getc

I am writing a Perl Script to find out the frequency of occurrence of characters in a message. Here is the logic I am following:

- Read one char at a time from the message using getc() and store it into an array.
- Run a for loop starting from index 0 to the length of this array.
- This loop will read each char of the array and assign it to a temp variable.
- Run another for loop nested in the above, which will run from the index of the character    being tested till the length of the array.
- Using a string comparison between this character and the current array indexed char, a counter is incremented if they are equal.
- After completion of inner For Loop, I am printing the frequency of the char for debug purposes.

Question: I don't want the program to recompute the frequency of a character if it's already been calculated. For instance, if character "a" occurs 3 times, for the first run, it calculates the correct frequency. However, at the next occurrence of "a", since loop runs from that index till the end, the frequency is (actual freq -1). Similary for the third occurrence, frequency is (actual freq -2).

To solve this. I used another temp array to which I would push the char whose frequency is already evaluated.

And then at the next run of for loop, before entering the inner for loop, I compare the current char with the array of evaluated chars and set a flag. Based on that flag, the inner for loop runs.

This is not working for me. Still the same results.

Here's the code I have written to accomplish the above:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input=$ARGV[0];
my ($c,$ch,$flag,$s,@arr,@temp);

open(INPUT,"<$input");

while(defined($c = getc(INPUT)))
{
push(@arr,$c);
}

close(INPUT);

my $length=$#arr+1;

for(my $i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
{
$count=0;
$flag=0;
$ch=$arr[$i];
foreach $s (@temp)
{
    if($ch eq $s)
    {
        $flag = 1;
    }
}
if($flag == 0)
{
for(my $k=$i;$k<$length;$k++)
{
    if($ch eq $arr[$k])
    {
        $count = $count+1;
    }
}
push(@temp,$ch);
print "The character \"".$ch."\" appears ".$count." number of times in the         message"."\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a single character count for the whole file then use any of the suggested methods posted by the others. If you want a count of *all* the occurances
of each character in a file then I propose:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# read in the contents of the file
my $contents;
open(TMP, "<$ARGV[0]") or die ("Failed to open $ARGV[0]: $!");
{
    local($/) = undef;
    $contents = <TMP>;
}
close(TMP);

# split the contents around each character
my @bits = split(//, $contents);

# build the hash of each character with it's respective count
my %counts = map { 
    # use lc($_) to make the search case-insensitive
    my $foo = $_; 

    # filter out newlines
    $_ ne "\n" ? 
        ($foo => scalar grep {$_ eq $foo} @bits) :
        () } @bits;

# reverse sort (highest first) the hash values and print
foreach(reverse sort {$counts{$a} <=> $counts{$b}} keys %counts) {
    print "$_: $counts{$_}\n";
}
```

Comment: For the record, `lc` only makes ASCII case-insensitive, not Unicode.

Comment: Amazing solution! It's so efficient. Thanks for giving a good example of the usage of grep and map function. This gives me one more reason to love grep :)

Answer (score 4):

You're making your life much harder than it needs to be. Use a hash:

```
my %freq;

while(defined($c = getc(INPUT)))
{
  $freq{$c}++;
}

print $_, " ", $freq{$_}, "\n" for sort keys %freq;
```

`$freq{$c}++` increments the value stored in `$freq{$c}`. (If it was unset or zero, it becomes one.)

The print line is equivalent to:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %freq) {
  print $key, " ", $freq{$key}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Mat's method is more efficient and a lot more simple than my solution! +1

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Now, I am clear with the concept of hashes in Perl and how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I don´t understand the problem you are trying to solve, so I propose a more simple way to count the characters in a string:

```
$string = "fooooooobar";
$char = 'o';
$count = grep {$_ eq $char} split //, $string;
print $count, "\n";
```

This prints the number of $char occurrences in $string (7).
Hope this helps to write a more compact code

Answer (score 2):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -F"" -anE '$h{$_}++ for @F; END { say "$_ : $h{$_}" for keys %h }' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster solution :

```
@result = $subject =~ m/a/g; #subject is your file

print "Found : ", scalar @result, " a characters in file!\n";
```

Of course you can put a variable in the place of 'a' or even better execute this line for whatever characters you want to count the occurrences.